# Split screen map and streetview

Tags: google-maps-urls

Google’s [2017 map documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/guide) does not say how to specify a split screen, lower part map, upper part streetview. Please, is this possible within a Google-map URL, and if it is, how?

Comment: If anybody knows, or even reasonably suspects, that it can’t be done, that would help. The question merely asks how [this](http://www.google.co.uk/maps/@?cid=4115942643000130790&api=1&map_action=pano&viewpoint=51.5042,-0.0934337&heading=-15&pitch=0&zoom=18) can be shown half-half streetview and map.

Comment: I didn't hear or read anything about that they have removed it. In [this documentation with example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-service) its still described and works.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't give any more information about the language you use, im just gonna link the documentation from google.

Since its still usable, the realtime examples work and they haven't said a word in changelog or else, I would assume its still working.

Here you can get to the overall [Google API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/web/)

As an exmaple for the question, [Google made a realtime Example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/streetview-service) with documentation, here in JS.

Also, even if its not possible to do in a short way, you can simply build two synchronized boxes. It just would take more effort.

Comment: Thank you, but the link is to be embedded in the OUTline of a PDF. E.g., as in http://www.jdawiseman.com/2017/20171102_1970s.pdf

Which limits my enthusiasm for scripting or the joining of multiple boxes.

Comment: @jdaw Without some sort of scripting it won’t be possible. And when you need a URL to do so, it won’t be possible to perform a side by side Street View.

Comment: Thank you. I think that there not being an answer isn’t an answer, so I’m not marking this as the answer. Because there isn’t one.

Comment: @jdaw1 I think the same way. Didn’t knew you wanted it in a pdf.